# PHP paginate string problem

Tags: php, string, pagination

i have this script

```
$content = string
if(!isset($_GET['page'])){
$page = 1;
}
else{
$page = $_GET['page']; 
}

while($content[$limit]!= ' '){
$limit++;
}
print substr($content,($page-1)*$limit, $limit);
```

it works just fine first time (if the page is not set or page number is 1 )but if my page number is greater than 1 it splits my words. cause $limit is increased and even $limit is set to an offset that corresponds to a space character the start in the substr() function is increased too and it basically shifts the whole chunk and the last character that i get is not my wanted space but first couple of letters after the space.(i hope i made myself understood). how can i fix this problem? thanks

Comment: hmm...but how to use it; i want to make a pagination script and that doesn't look right for what i'm trying to do, wordwrap returns a string.(if it was returning an array it was even better than my script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
print substr($content, ($page-1) *  $limit, strpos  ( $content, ' ' , ($page-1) *  $limit));
```

This says:

> Take the sub-string of $content,
>   starting at the given page * the limit
>   for each page, and given me all the
>   characters up to the position of the
>   next space.

Answer (score 1):

As [Frank Farmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82769/frank-farmer) said, use [wordwrap](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php), but with a weird delimiter. Then use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) with that delimiter to get an array.

```
$limit = 500; // max chars per page?
$content = "lots of text ..."; // the whole article?

if(!isset($_GET['page'])){
   $page = 1;
} else {
   $page = intval($_GET['page']); 
}

$pages = explode("@BREAK@", wordwrap($content, $limit, "@BREAK@"));

print $pages[$page-1];
```